# "bin" a tuple of values in python without using loops

Tags: python

i've got a `tuple` listed as such:

```
example = (255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 254, 255, 255, 255, 247, 255, 255, 247, 254)
```

what i'm trying to do, is to get it to be represented as `11111111` (for 255) and `11110111` (for 247) etc etc.

I found that with python3, [bin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin), you can achieve this with:

```
>>> format(14, '#b'), format(14, 'b')
('0b1110', '1110')

>>>f'{14:#b}', f'{14:b}'
('0b1110', '1110')
```

One easy way of doing this for `example` would be to do it from a `for` loop, to recursively convert the values and append to a buffer.

But is there a way to directly format `example` so that it is pythonic and efficient?

Comment: No way without a for loop of some kind (map or comprehension)

Comment: You *will* need a loop of some kind, since every element needs to be touched. The only choice is whether this is visible or hidden behind some abstraction. What is your criteria to consider a solution "loop free"?

Comment: Program will need to reach out to each element anyway, so, I guess that it can't be faster than `O(n)`. In that case `for` loop seems reasonable. I consider that example is small enough to fit in your ram, otherwise you'll need to use some temporary buffers.

Comment: What is your expected output, and what is your own attempt to produce it? "Pythonic" does not mean "I didn't use a `for` loop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you want to output that all into single string. I think it is the most pythonic way to do that:

```py
''.join(map(lambda x: f'{x:b}', example))
```

Output:

```py
'1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111111111111111111111011111111111111111111111011111111110'
```

Comment: Map + lambda seems rather clunky when you can use list comprehension instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a function to an iterable using the map function without doing any loop. By using map python will take care of doing the loop over the iterable and it will be faster than any for loop.

Something like this will be faster than any list comprehension or loop:

```
result = map(bin,list)
```

In python3 map function returns an iterator that you can convert back to a list or tuple using list() or tuple()

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` to apply a transformation function to an arbitrary iterable. This produces an iterator, which can be iterated directly or converted to a `list`, `tuple`, or other type.

```
>>> tuple(map(bin, example))
('0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111110', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11110111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11110111', '0b11111110')
```

Note that `map` internally uses a loop, which is however still more efficient than a regular Python `for`. Realistically, the bulk of runtime is spent on the transformation, not the method of application (`map`, comprehension, `for`-loop, ...), though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is pretty pythonic:

```
bin_example = [ bin(ex) for ex in example ]
# ['0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111110', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11110111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11110111', '0b11111110']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use comprehension, like this:

```py
example = (255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 254, 255, 255, 255, 247, 255, 255, 247, 254)

example = tuple(f"{ex:b}" for ex in example)
print(example)
# ('11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111110', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11110111', '11111111', '11111111', '11110111', '11111110')
```